Error During Prerendering in Next.js: redirect() Not Working as Expected in / Page During npm run build
I'm encountering an error during prerendering of the / page when running npm run build in my Next.js app. Everything works fine during development (npm run dev), but when I try to build and export the project using npm run build, I get the following error:

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Export encountered errors on following paths: /(dashboard)/page: /

Related Code
//File Location: src/app/(dashboard)/page.tsx

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { getCurrent } from "@/features/auth/queries";
import { getWorkspaces } from "@/features/workspaces/queries";

export default async function Home() {
  const user = await getCurrent();
  if (!user) redirect("/sign-in");

  const workspaces = await getWorkspaces();
  if (workspaces.total === 0) {
    redirect("/workspaces/create");
  } else {
    redirect(`/workspaces/${workspaces.documents[0].$id}`);
  }
}

